# Kubernetes nodes on different datacenters causes slowness

Tags: kubernetes

We have 2 datacenters (A and B) on 2 different regions (Eastern and Central). I've setup K8S single cluster where master is on datacenter A and few nodes on both datacenters. Our application contains 3 images (AppServer, DB, ReportingServer). Consider these 2 scenarios when the application is deployed:

1 - All 3 pods are created on the nodes belong to datacenter A. Everything works fine.

2 - DB pod or AppServer pod is created on a node belong to datacenter B and the other 2 pods are created on datacenter A. In this case application is very slow, takes 10-15 mins for it to be in running state (instead of 2-3 mins), login page loads very slowly and logging to the application usually throws error due to timeout.

My question: Is it normal for K8S to behave like this if nodes are in different datacenters? Or my setup is wrong?

Comment: Are you using any cloud provider? Is the delay happening only in k8s? Any bottlenecks that might slow communication between the DCs?

Comment: No, it's not cloud. Two on premises datacenters. It happens only in K8S. I tested the local installation (DB on datacenter A and AppServer on datacenter B) and there is no such issue as significant slowness. It happens only with K8S. I was wondering if it's a normal behavior for K8S like k8s doesn't like to have its nodes on different datacenters and all (master and nodes) should be in the same datacenter?